# Matlab Finite function

Tags: matlab

Is there a companion function to isinf(x), similar to real(x) and isreal(x)?

```
x = [0,1,345,inf]
a = isreal(x)
b = real(x) = 0,1,345,inf

c = isinf(x)
%does this exist?
d = finite(x) = 0,1,345
```

Comment: `real` returns the real component of complex number. What would your `finite` return? You cannot split a number into a finite and an infinite component. Why don’t you show, with an example input and output, what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Finite(x) would return the finite numbers contained within matrix or array (x), much like real(x) returns the real numbers in x... added numbers to explain... as per the example provided in question prior to edits. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity

Comment: I’ll note that your proposed `finite()` is nothing like `real()`. The latter returns an array of the same size as the input, transforming each number independently. Your proposed function filters the values, returning only the ones that match the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function, but it is really easy to get this result, simply combine `isfinite()` with indexing:

```
d = x(isfinite(x))
```